# Update text in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rest

Quite new to programming, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I have two (very similar) functions:

```
function getRingNumbers(queueID, divID) {

    $.ajax({
        url: `https://api.mypurecloud.de/api/v2/routing/queues/${queueID}/users`,
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + globalToken);},
        success: function(data) {            
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.entities.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
                    div.innerHTML += '<center><p class="odd">' + data.entities[i].ringNumber + '</p></center>';
                }
                else {
                    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
                    div.innerHTML += '<center><p class="even">' + data.entities[i].ringNumber + '</p></center>';
                }
            } 
        }        
    });
}
```

and

```
function updateRingNumbers(queueID, divID) {

    $.ajax({
        url: `https://api.mypurecloud.de/api/v2/routing/queues/${queueID}/users`,
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + globalToken);},
        success: function(data) {            
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.entities.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
                    div.innerHTML = '<center><p class="odd">' + data.entities[i].ringNumber + '</p></center>';
                }
                else {
                    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
                    div.innerHTML = '<center><p class="even">' + data.entities[i].ringNumber + '</p></center>';
                }
            } 
        }        
    });
}
```

I want to run the second function on a 30 seconds interval, so it keeps the ring numbers updated. The only thing I changed in the code, is remove the + before the = @ div.innerHTML (+)=. From all the documentation I can find on the internet, this should update the div with the new information. However, I keep getting 'undefined' and it just clears the ring number data. When I run the first function on an interval, this does work, but this keeps creating divs which isn't what I want.

Anyone knows what is causing this, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Even if you fix the `undefined` problem, this will just set the DIV to the last ring number. You're overwriting the HTML each time through the loop.

Comment: So how are you calling it?

Comment: `div.innerHTML = ....` will only every show the last entry.... You need to reset the innerHTML before you loop.

Comment: I don't understand why you changed `+=` to `=`. You need `+=` if you want to concatenate all the entities.

Comment: FYI, not sure why you are using <center> which is obsolete, use text-align. And there is no need to add odd and even classes, you can just do all of that in CSS. `#myId p:nth-child(odd) { }`

Comment: Wow, can’t believe I didn’t think of this... inexperience I guess. So clearing the innerHTML like document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = ""; and re adding the += before running the loop should fix this right? I didn’t realise Center is obsolete, will change that. I tried using the nth-child but somehow it didn’t work for me, that’s why I did it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the innerHTML and still concatenate to it. Without the += you are only going to see the last entry. You can use innerHTML with or create elements. I prefer creating elements.

```
    success: function(data) {
      var div = document.getElementById(divID);
      // empty the content
      div.innerHTML = '';
      // loop over your array
      data.entities.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        // create a p element
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        // set your class
        p.className = index % 2 == 1 ? 'odd' ? 'even';
        // add the text
        p.textContent = data.entities[i].ringNumber;
        // add it to your div
        div.appendChild(p);
      })
    }
```

Now you can just use CSS to control the odd or even and center the content with text-align.

```css
#myWrapper p {
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center
}

#myWrapper p:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div id="myWrapper">
  <p>Bacon 1</p>
  <p>Bacon 2</p>
  <p>Bacon 3</p>
  <p>Bacon 4</p>
  <p>Bacon 5</p>
  <p>Bacon 6</p>
</div>
```